# Returning relevant value from another array in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have two arrays filled with strings that are relational. I need to pull back the value from array 2 whilst iterating through array 1 in a foreach loop. How your i Achieve this? Here is my code:

```
$contracts = @("xytt"
               "deff"
               "mnoo")

$labels = @("London contract"
            "Dubai contract"
            "Glasgow contract")

foreach ($contract in $contracts){
#Do stuff with $contract
#Return label associated to contract object
}
```

Comment: How are the two arrays related?  For example, when I look at 'xytt' in `$contracts`, how do I know which item in `$labels` it is related to?  Unless you are stuck with this arrangement of data for some reason, I'd consider setting it up a different way.

Comment: Hi, 

They are squential. So [0]$Contract is associated to [0]$Label and so on.

Comment: Just as an FYI, for related data a Hash or Dictionary is generally a better data structure than related arrays.

Comment: How would i build these two arrays in to a hash table to query?

Comment: How do you generate the arrays in the first place?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by query? An array of custom objects would probably more powershell canonical depending on how you get the data and what you want to do with it.

Comment: They are pre defined values, not calculated. I would then want to iterate through each value from $contracts in current form and use the data to build strings for processing.

Comment: What do you mean by predefined? Are they leterals that you code in your script? Are you reading them from a CSV? Text file? Querying a database? How do the variables get instantiated and populated?

Comment: They are in the script, so hard coded.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `for` loop and an index variable instead of `foreach`:

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt $contracts.Length; $i++) {
    $contract = $contracts[$i]
    $label = $labels[$i]
    Write-Host "$contract : $label"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with EBGreen, a hash table is more suited to the task.

Similarly to Janne Tuukkanen's script this one uses an index,
but based on a normal ForEach.

```
ForEach ($contract in $contracts){
    "{0} - {1}" -f $contract, $labels[$contracts.IndexOf($contract)]
}
```

Sample output:

```
xytt - London contract
deff - Dubai contract
mnoo - Glasgow contract
```

Comment: This makes a not necessarily valid assumption that all the entries in $contracts are unique.

Comment: @EBGreen You are right, a hash table would reveal that at an earlier point.

Comment: Not if you use $labels as the keys for the hash and they are unique.